# Install iOS 8 after iOS 9 release

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, ios9

I don't know is SO is the best place to ask this, but this is related to iOS development so here it goes :

For development purposes, I have kept an iPhone under iOS 7. With the official release of iOS 9 coming soon, I will probably drop support for iOS 7 and need to upgrade this iPhone to iOS 8 (again, for development purposes).

My question : Will it be possible to upgrade to iOS 8 (from iOS 7) once iOS 9 is out, or will the iPhone only let me upgrade directly to iOS 9 ?

Thanks (and please don't make any guesses, I'd like a definite answer, maybe from someone who experienced this situation last year)

Comment: Well I'm still supporting iOS 7, so I would like to avoid this. I'll do it only if I have no other choice.

Comment: Download update via iTunes, save the file and don't install iOs 8. When you decide to update alt+click the Update button and select the file. It's been like that for years and I don't see a reason of why they would change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that if obtain a copy of the iOS 8 download now, and keep that file saved somewhere then as long as it is still signed you should be able to install it.

Plug the iPhone in, open iTunes, click on the summery tab hold down Alt (Or Options) and you should get a file dialog window, browse to the downloaded version of iOS 8 and you should be set.

Bear in mind Apple normally stops signing older versions of iOS pretty quickly after new versions come out, so this might not continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing you can download both iOS 8.4.1 and iOS 9 GM Seed from [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/).  Once you have downloaded iOS 8, you can upgrade your phone from iOS 7 via iTunes.

So download it now, ready for when you want to upgrade, as Apple don't provide links to older versions of iOS, as far as I can see (not even on their developer download site).  You can probably get older versions from *alternative sites*, but then you have to trust those sites.